# Parse number with parentheses as negative

Tags: oracle, oracle11gr2

I have a VARCHAR2 that is populated from parsing a CSV file uploaded by end users (which is likely to have been converted from Microsoft Excel). One of the columns must be the dollar amount, and we want the program to accept most unambiguous numeric amounts (positive or negative) but reject anything that doesn't look like a number (e.g. if the user uploads the wrong spreadsheet).

Values to accept:

```
12345.6789
12345.67
12345.6
12345.
12345
12,345.67
$12345.67
-12345.67
-12,345.67
(12,345.67)
```

Values to reject:

```
FRED
12%345
BLAH123
£12345.67
```

Negotiable*:

```
(12345.67
12)345.67
12$345.67
1,23,4,5.67
12,345.67-
12 345.67
```

This is the code we had previously, which didn't cover all cases:

```
TO_NUMBER(TRANSLATE(val,'0$,','0'))
```

If this raises an exception (`VALUE_ERROR` or `ORA-01858` "non-numeric character") we report a suitable error message to the user. It correctly handles all the above cases except for parentheses.

* *(negotiable because I don't want to write a page-long piece of code to try to handle every possible permutation; it needs to be maintainable and handle the more likely formats that users might use)*

*TL;DR* There is a PR number format element for showing a negative number with parentheses (<> actually) but it doesn't work for TO_NUMBER to convert strings to numbers.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6ba12/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my naïve approach thus far:

```
TO_NUMBER(
   RTRIM(LTRIM(
     TRANSLATE(val,'0$ ','0')
     ,'('),')')
   ,'999999999999999999990D000000'
   ,'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''.,''')
* CASE WHEN val LIKE '(%)' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END
```